# env(safe-area-inset-bottom) in CSS doesn't work in Unity webview in IOS 16.3.1 IPhone 13 Pro

Tags: css, ios, unity-game-engine, webview

env(safe-area-inset-bottom) in CSS in Webview doesn't work. the value apears 0px.

I've added `viewport-fit=cover` to the meta tag in the html file like beblow

```html
    <meta
      name="viewport"
      content="viewport-fit=cover, width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=0"
    />
```

App: Unity

OS: IOS 16.3.1

Device: IPhone 13 Pro

It might be a problem of webview browser version or Unity itself.
I am a web developer don't know much of Unity and mobile development.

Could you help me?